# How to pass value of a switch in objective c xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a field in my table named as is_active in core data table with Boolean type.

I have a on-off switch in my storyboard.

I want to enter the value into the database table in both cases if switch is on and if switch is off.

e.g :like i am entering the name of category

```
[newCategory setValue:self.txtEnterName.text forKey:@"name"];
```

same like i want to enter the value against the switch on and off.

I am using this and i know this is completely wrong...

```
if (self.txtIsActive.isOn) {
    [newCategory setValue:self.txtIsActive.1 forKey:@"is_active"];
} else {
    [newCategory setValue:self.txtIsActive.0 forKey:@"is_active"];
}
```

but i want to enter 0 and 1 values into my database against the on and of depends upon which one is selected.

**OKAY GUYS**

i have edited my code THANKS TO MR 
Ramy Al Zuhouri

```
    if (self.txtIsActive.isOn)
 {
 [newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.isOn) forKey:@"is_active"]; 
}
 else
{
 [newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.tag == '0') forKey:@"is_active"]; 
}
```

this is what i need o and 1 against off and on in database.

Comment: What's wrong with just `[newCategory setValue:self.txtIsActive.isOn forKey:@"is_active"]`?

Comment: @CarlNorum in your case it says

Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.isOn) forKey:@"is_active"];
```

The `@` is used to create a `NSNumber` with the value between round parenthesis.

Comment: what will be the else condition like if i write it like this...
   
    `if (self.txtIsActive.isOn) {
        [newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.isOn) forKey:@"is_active"];
    }
    else
    {
        
    }`

Comment: Without if-else, it's already ok: a boolean is like a number, with the difference that it's value can be 1 or 0. You're just making a plain assignment.

Comment: ahan so i guess in else case it will automatically enter a 0?

Comment: Its adding 1 when switch is on and null when it is off but if in future i want to fetch records where is_active = o then what will i do it should be 0 what will you prefer.

Comment: self.txtISActive.isOn can be 1 or 0. This method call is always executed, it's not like an if statement. So newCategory.is_active will be 1 or 0.

Comment: Mashallah your knowledge is great.

Comment: i have edited my code like this and know its that what i need.

`if (self.txtIsActive.isOn) {
        [newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.isOn) forKey:@"is_active"];
    }
    else{
        
    [newCategory setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.tag == '0') forKey:@"is_active"];
        
    }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059128/how-to-manage-data-between-the-entities-with-the-uipickerview/19087212?noredirect=1#comment28224930_19087212
please help me to sorting this out...

Answer (score 1):

A coreData Boolean maps to a NSNumber, so you can set it directly as

```
newCategory.is_active = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.txtIsActive.isOn];
```

Comment: it says 
Property 'is_active' not found on object of type 'NSManagedObject *'

Comment: In that case, [newCategory setValue:[NSNumberWithBool:self.txtIsActive.isOn];

Comment: MR WIL MAC can you write it into a condition like if else coz i want to enter the value in 0 and 1.

Comment: self.txtIsActive.isOn will be either TRUE or FALSE, so the statement above doesn't need to be turned into a condition.