# How to manage data between the entities with the UIPICKERVIEW?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uipickerview

I have a scenario in my basic inventory app.

i fetched the records from the core data entity and want other records to be entered against that one.

I have two core data entities Category and Product

i have made their relationship as well.

i have done with the category part.

now i want to add Products against the selected category.

for that i am using a `UIPICKERVIEW` to show the category name.

I am currently showing the names to the `UIPICKERVIEW`

**When the user select the name and enter records the `id` should be stored in the Product entity where the relational field is.**

Currently the UIPICKERVIEW is showing the name of the category from the Category table

where their is a form to insert the data to the Product table against that category.

In Simple i want to show names in the picker and in backend the id will be stored against that name.

In Category.h entity i have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * is_active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descript;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *products;
```

IN Product.h I have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * is_active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descript;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Category *category;
```

IMSAddProductViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IMSAppDelegate.h"

@interface IMSAddProductViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEnterName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtEnterDescription;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *txtIsActive;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblValuePicker;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arr;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;

- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender;



@end
```

Getting results From Entity 1 Category

IMSAddProductViewController.m  //(UIViewController sub class)

```
#import "IMSAddProductViewController.h"
#import "IMSAppDelegate.h"
#import "Product.h"
#import "Category.h"

@interface IMSAddProductViewController ()
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context;

}
@end

@implementation IMSAddProductViewController
@synthesize arr;
@synthesize txtIsActive;
@synthesize categoryArray;
@synthesize txtEnterName;
@synthesize txtEnterDescription;
@synthesize categoryPicker;
@synthesize lblValuePicker;



  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.categoryPicker.delegate = self;


    IMSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *category = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc ] init];

    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    [request setEntity:category];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]

                                        initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

//    request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[category propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];

    request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;


    NSError *error;

    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

   // NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    if (array == nil) {

        //error handle here
    }
    NSArray* results2 = [array valueForKeyPath:@"name"];

    [self setArr:results2];

    // [self setArr:results];

    NSLog (@"name: %@",self.arr);



}

//-(void) addProducts:(NSSet *)values {
//     
//}



- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   // return _countryNames.count;
    return self.arr.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //return _countryNames[row];
    return self.arr[row];
}




   -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    categoryArray = [self.arr objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog (@"name: %@",self.categoryArray );
    // both of these are returning the name of categories.
    self.categoryPicker = [self.arr objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog (@"name: %@",self.categoryPicker);

    NSLog(@"id : %d", row);


}
```

THE CODE WHERE I AM INSERTING DATA TO PRODUCT

```
  - (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSManagedObject *newProduct = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newProduct setValue:self.txtEnterName.text forKey:@"name"];

    [newProduct setValue:self.txtEnterDescription.text forKey:@"descript"];

    if (self.txtIsActive.isOn) {

        [newProduct setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.isOn) forKey:@"is_active"];
    }

    else{

        [newProduct setValue: @(self.txtIsActive.tag == '0') forKey:@"is_active"];

    }



    // what should be done in this block of code
    /*
    lblValuePicker.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.categoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSLog(@"row number: %@", lblValuePicker.text);
    [newProduct setValue:lblValuePicker.text forKey:@"category"];
    */


    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error]) {

        //handle the error

        NSLog(@"some error");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"dataentered");
    }

}
```

HERE IS THE SNAPSHOT I HAVE IT FROM `BASE`

[image]

THE CORE DATA IT SELF MANAGES THE INDEXES I HAVEN'T CREATE ANY ID OR PRIMARY KEY FOR THAT.

Comment: Almost Same problem is here.

Comment: What value Should be entered in the ZCATEGORY column???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
I would suggest you read this Official documentation on [How to create, initialize and save a Managed Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdCreateMOs.html).

2.
Understand when you select the row in picker view then the below delegate is called, in which I can see you have used an array. This is wrong:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    categoryArray = [self.arr objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

From the selected row, you would get only the name of the Category because that is in the array. I guess you must be getting an error here, because you are equilating an `NSString` to an array. 
To do it correctly I would suggest you to change the previous code as well. Instead, of fetching only name property from Category entity from Core Data, you fetch the whole Category entities.

I can give you code here but that wont be any good for you. You must try first.

Fetch the whole Category Entity, use a sort desciptor for 'name'- otherwise it may create problem later and in `UIPickerView`- `titleForRow` delegate method,  use dot(.) operator to display name.

3.
 Change your `didSelectRow` implementation. Donot put anything in the array. You need the selected Category to map against the newly created Product.
Create an instance variable of type Category, and using `objectAtIndex` method, get the corresponding Category and put it inside your instance variable.

4.
 In `btnSave` method, use the instance variable to map your Product against the selectedCategory. Please go through he link mentioned above to understand how to create, initialize and save the managed object, because I can see you are using a lot of key- value coding which is though not wrong, but is not the largely followed policy.

Comment: bro i need your help surely i have edited it a lil bit but still need help

Comment: Edit the question here with updated code. We will work on it.