# how to show the names from one entity in a uipickerview and store the id of selective option to the other entity where the relationship exist?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want to show the names from one entity in a `uipickerview` and store the id of selective

option to the other entity where the relationship exist.

[How to manage data between the entities with the UIPICKERVIEW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059128/how-to-manage-data-between-the-entities-with-the-uipickerview?noredirect=1#comment28169246_19059128).

you can visit this link.

Currently getting the names in uipickerview

Comment: @rmaddy can you visit the link as well...

Comment: you should check the docs and do some tutorials. It's not even really quite clear what you're asking at this point...

Comment: @buildsucceeded look i have 2 entities in my core data db 1 category 2 product

Comment: both have name descript and is_active.... but if i want to make a int type auto increment field and assign as pk there is no option for that.

Comment: the relationship between these two entities is there

Comment: what i want that i am currently displaying names from the Category entity and want to store what value should be stored in `Product_Category_Index` which is the relationship made in database schema as column name "Category" in Product table.

Comment: @buildsucceeded have you got my point...